# How to write a converter in JOOQ to convert fields from String to Map<String, String>

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

How to convert a string field to map while fetching the data from DB in JOOQ

Comment: There are various ways. Can you please let us know what you want to do?

Comment: I want to convert it while writing a select statement and also while doing insert or update from string to map and map to string respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a [`Converter<String, Map<String, String>>`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Converter.html) and [attach that to your generated code as documented here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/).